# Truncate a directory in bash

Tags: bash, directory, truncate

Is there some elegant/simple way to delete the folder's contents in such a way there's no error output if it is empty?

The following command

```
$ rm -r $dir/*
```

doesn't work if the directory is empty, since in such a case, the wilcard `*` is not expanded and you get an error saying that `rm` cannot find file `*`.

Of course, the standard way is check if it is empty (with `ls $dir | wc -w` or `find $dir -link 2` or any other related command), and deleting its contents otherwise.

Is there an alternative way not to check folder contents and only "truncate" the directory instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Bash

Simply,

```
$ rm -rf dir/*
```

(By default I believe) Bash doesn't complain about not finding anything with the glob.  It just passes your literal glob through to your command:

```
$ echo dir/*
dir/*
```

When `rm` doesn't find a filename that has the literal glob character, it complains about not finding the file it's been asked to delete:

```
$ rm "dir/*"
rm: cannot remove ‘dir/*’: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

But if you force it, it won't complain:

```
$ rm -f "dir/*"
$ echo $?
0
```

I don't know if that refrain-from-complain is POSIX.

Do note, however, that if you don't have the shell option "dotglob" set, you'll miss files that start with a dot, AKA "hidden" files.

## Generally

Zsh doesn't pass the literal glob through by default.  You have to ask for it with "`set -o nonomatch`".

```
$ echo dir/*
zsh: no matches found: dir/*
$ echo $?
1
$ set -o nonomatch
$ echo dir/*
dir/*
```

For compatibility, I wouldn't use the above modern-Bash-specific "`rm -rf dir/*`", but would use the more general, widely-compatible solution:

```
$ find dir -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Find all files in "dir" at a minimum depth of 1 ("dir" itself is at depth 0), and delete them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rm -rf`:

```
rm -rf "$dir"/*
```

As per `man bash`:

```
  -f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

Comment: ... I made the question too fast. Obvious solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf dir/*
```

does not delete hidden files which name starts with dot.

This is quite weird, when bash glob the *, it does not include .* files.

```
mkdir -p dir
touch dir/.a
rm -fr dir/*
ls dir/.a && echo I am not deleted
```

output is

```
dir/.a
I am not deleted
```

Besides, the `rm -fr dir/*` has another disadvantage: when there are too many files in the dir, the `rm` command will get too many arguments and results in error `too many arguments`. Also, it is very slow in that case.

Seems that the most reliable and fastest way is

```
find dir -mindepth 1 -delete
```